# How to upload file from local python script to Azure container?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a json file directly from my python script (VSC) to an Azure blob container.

Here is what I've tried:

```
account_url = "https://containerxyz.blob.core.windows.net"
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)

container_name = 'https://containerxyz.blob.core.windows.net/a/b/raw/'

file = 'test.txt'
contents = 'test'
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=contents)
blob_client.upload_blob(name=file, data=contents, overwrite=True)
```

I don't even get an error code, it just runs and never stops and I eventually interrupt the kernel after a couple minutes.

The same thing happens when I try it a bit differently:

```
data = 'test'
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container=container_name)
container_client.upload_blob(name="test.txt", data=data, overwrite=True)
```

I've tried following the Azure docs but they always use examples that take a local file and upload it to azure using "with open(...)" e.g: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python

If I run everything before the `upload_blob()` function it runs without errors so I'm assuming the problem is there.

Comment: _it just runs and never stops_ Sounds like it could be a network firewall issue.  Are you running this code from a machine that is behind a restrictive network firewall?

Comment: There's an issue with the container name `container_name = 'https://containerxyz.blob.core.windows.net/a/b/raw/'`.  What's the account name of your storage account and blob container name?

Comment: @GauravMantri my account name is "containerxyz", in that account I have multiple directories and I want to upload the blob to "/a/b/raw". So the container name is "a/b/raw"? I tried this and got the same issue.

Comment: Added an answer. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

> my account name is "containerxyz", in that account I have multiple
> directories and I want to upload the blob to "/a/b/raw". So the
> container name is "a/b/raw"? I tried this and got the same issue.

In this case, the container name would be `a`. If you want to upload data in `b/raw` folder (which is virtual BTW), you would need to include this in the name of the blob.

So your code would be something like:

```
account_url = "https://containerxyz.blob.core.windows.net"
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)

container_name = 'a'

file = 'b/raw/test.txt'
contents = 'test'
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file)
blob_client.upload_blob(name=file, data=contents, overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't even get an error code, it just runs and never stops and I eventually interrupt the kernel after a couple of minutes

I agree with Gaurav Mantri's comment, the issue may be using an incorrect storage account or container name.

I tried in my environment with proper **`account url`** and **`container name`** it executed successfully.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient


account_url = "https://<your-storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net"
default_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url, credential=default_credential)
container_name = 'test1' #your-container-name
file = 'test.txt'
content=b"test"
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=file)
blob_client.upload_blob(data=content, overwrite=True)

print(f"File {file} uploaded to blob {blob_client.blob_name} in container {blob_client.container_name}")
```

**Output:**

```
File test.txt uploaded to blob test.txt in container test1
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Upload a blob with Python - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload-python)

Comment: Say you create a directory in "venkat123" called "a", then in "a" you create a directory "b", and in "b" you create a directory "c". What would be your container name if you want to upload to a container under directory, "a/b/c"?

Comment: @Mitch "venkat123" is account name and container is "test" in my code.